# Spark Scala how to process multiple columns in single loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Bellow rows are dataframe for Mango,Apple,Orange columns respectively

```
   [10,20,30]
   [100,2000,300]
   [1000,200,3000]
```

For the above dataframe: I need to get a summary like

```
{Mango: 1110; Apple:2220; Orange:3330 }
```

How do i do this with Single iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple `dataframe` as below

```
+-----+-----+------+
|Mango|Apple|Orange|
+-----+-----+------+
|10   |20   |30    |
|100  |200  |300   |
|1000 |2000 |3000  |
+-----+-----+------+
```

you can do something like below

```
df.select(sum("Mango").as("Mango"), sum("Apple").as("Apple"), sum("Orange").as("Orange")).toJSON.rdd.foreach(println)
```

which would give you output as

```
{"Mango":1110,"Apple":2220,"Orange":3330}
```